# display custom tile for missing tiles in google maps app

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps

I am working with google maps in flash, and i would like to know how to serve up my own image tile for the "we have no imagery at this zoom level..." error.

I dont want to serve up an entire map of images - just for the times when google has no image

- does the tile layer base dispatch an event? (i couldnt find any in the api)
- is there a method that can be overridden by extending the tilelayerbase class

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/CustomMapRoadTrip/CustomMapRoadTrip.html

I'm pretty sure this does what you need ^ ?

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-maps-api-for-flash%2Ft7oYId6UeI0%2Fdiscussion

Comment: Hi Shaun, unfortunately not. The first example loads a custile tile layer with tiles that make a tabbed grid. When these tiles fail to load it generates a custom fail tile instead. This contains no relation to failed map layer images.

the second example only colours loaded map images and does not contain anh information regarding failed images on the map layer.

the third option would be to extend the tileLayerBase.as but then you are not permitted to load images directly from the google servers.

Comment: @Beans, ah I just re-read your post I see where I went wrong there, was thinking you were looking for the fail image the second link was just meant to be a more general reference of where I found the first, sorry wasn't very explicit thought that one was an easy answer, sorry bout that... I don't know about solving the tiles not available at this zoom level, but I understand the issue now, if I find anything I'll post back.